# Determine SouthWest and NorthEast of Indoor Atlas floor plan image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios, indoor-positioning-system

I am trying to build one small example using IndoorAtlas SDK for indoor navigation. I am using Google Maps instead of Apple Maps.
Once I fetch the floor plan image from the IndoorAtlas backend I need to create GMSCoordinateBounds which requires SouthWest and NorthEast coordinates to create bounds. I need to know how can I determine these coordinates correctly.
Currently my code looks something like this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.floorPlan.topRight.latitude,self.floorPlan.topRight.longitude);
CLLocationCoordinate2D northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.floorPlan.bottomLeft.latitude,self.floorPlan.bottomLeft.longitude);


GMSCoordinateBounds *overlayBounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:southWest coordinate:northEast];


UIImage *icon = fpImage;
GMSGroundOverlay *overlay =
[GMSGroundOverlay groundOverlayWithBounds:overlayBounds icon:icon];
overlay.bearing = self.floorPlan.bearing;
overlay.map = _mapView;

GMSCameraUpdate *updatedCamera = [GMSCameraUpdate setTarget:self.floorPlan.center zoom:10];
[self.mapView animateWithCameraUpdate:updatedCamera];
self.marker.position = self.camera.target;
_mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:self.camera];
```

How do I determine the mentioned coordinates. Trying the above coordinates I am not getting the correct rect.

Is there any other way to determine this?

Comment: did you find the solution? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to calculate the coordinates

-(NSArray *)calculateLongLatDegreesInMeters:(CLLocationDegrees)latitude
{

```
float lat = M_PI * latitude / 180;

// Constants for calculating lengths

float m1 = 111132.92;

float m2 = -559.82;

float m3 = 1.175;

float m4 = -0.0023;

float p1 = 111412.84;

float p2 = -93.5;

float p3 = 0.118;

float eq1 = m1 + (m2 * cos(2 * lat)) + (m3 * cos(4 * lat));

float latitudeDegreeInMeters = eq1 + (m4 * cos(6 * lat));

float longitudeDegreeInMeters = (p1 * cos(lat)) + (p2 * cos(3 * lat)) +    (p3 * cos(5 * lat));

NSString *latDegInMtr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",latitudeDegreeInMeters];
NSString *lonDegInMtr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",longitudeDegreeInMeters];


NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:latDegInMtr,lonDegInMtr, nil];



return arr; //(latitudeDegreeInMeters, longitudeDegreeInMeters)
```

}